# How can I enable the textbox when the checkbox is check

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik-ajax

How can I enable the textbox when the checkbox is checked in JavaScript:

Can someone please show me how to do it correct please!
this is my code:

```
 function checkLevelZone() {
            var txtOffSite = $find("<%=txtOffSite.ClientID %>");
            var checkbox = $find("<%=OffSiteCheck.ClientID %>");
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                txtOffSite.removeAttribute('Enabled');
                } else {
                txtOffSite.disabled = true;
               }

            }
```

asp:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="OffSiteCheck" runat="server" ToggleType="CheckBox" ButtonType="ToggleButton"  OnClientCheckedChanged="checkLevelZone"  Skin="Windows7"></telerik:RadButton>
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtOffSite" runat="server" Enabled="false"> </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use the much older `$find` ASP function, rather than using jQuery to do this?

Comment: What is being rendered? A html checkbox or some typ of image or something?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
txtOffSite.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
function checkLevelZone() {
    var checkbox = $("#<%=OffSiteCheck.ClientID %>");
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        $("#<%=txtOffSite.ClientID %>").removeAttribute('disabled');
    } else {
        $("#<%=txtOffSite.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: r u getting any error? Also please make sure the checkLevelZone function is called.

Comment: I double checked it and the function is called but the text box is still disabled. :((

Comment: Updated the answer. Give it another try. It should work, if you still have problem, show us the rendered HTML for the textbox.

Comment: Line: 293
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'attr' this is the error that I got

Comment: Updated the answer again. try now.

Comment: make sure jQuery is referenced and loaded

Comment: <telerik:RadButton ID="OffSiteCheck" runat="server" ToggleType="CheckBox" ButtonType="ToggleButton"  OnClientCheckedChanged="checkLevelZone"  Skin="Windows7"></telerik:RadButton>
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtOffSite" runat="server" Enabled="false"> </telerik:RadTextBox>

Comment: This is not rendered HTML. Try to post the HTML that you get in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me....

$("#checkBoxId").change(function()
{

$("#textBoxId" />").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));

}) ;

Answer (score 0):

Since you used [OnClientCheckedChanged](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-onclientcheckedchanged.html), your function signature is incorrect.

```
function checkLevelZone(sender, args) {  
    if (args.get_checked()) { // Most rad controls use .set_enabled(true), the RadTextBox is different.
        $find('<%= txtOffSite.ClientID%>').enable();  // $find() works, $() doesn't always work.
    }
    else {    
        $find('<%= txtOffSite.ClientID%>').disable();
    }
}
```

[Online documentation for RadNumericTextBox](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-client-side-radnumerictextbox.html), most of which applies to RadTextBox